# Animate layout on different activities on android 4.4(kitkat) and higher

Tags: android, animation, android-4.4-kitkat

Now [this specific page does describe](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview) a way to animate between layouts of different activities, but the problem is that the API is only supported for android 5.0 and higher, so I'd like to know what are the ways in which animation(like transition or any other type of fade/slide in etc.) could be done for layouts in two different activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set transitions on your theme prior to Lollipop version but you can still use animations programmatically.

Here’s an example with animations that slide the new activity in when first created, and the opposite movement when you press the back button.

**left_in.xml**

```
<set>

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="-100%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="500"/> //in milliseconds
</set>
```

**right_in.xml**

```
<set>


    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="100%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**left_out.xml**

```
<set>

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="-100%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**right_out.xml**

```
<set>

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="100%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

On your activities you can call the animations as follows:

On start: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);`

On Back Pressed: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);`

Or any combination of the above.

**Note** that the first animation on `overridePendingTransition` is for the incoming activity and the second for the outgoing activity.

Comment: @NikosHidaigo, can you please tell me what is this method called and link the page describing this in the documentation? I mean it's the first time I've seen the `set` and the `translate` tag being used in Android so I'd like to understand this as well.

Comment: @juztcode have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int) and here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#View

Comment: @juztcode you can create a folder in your project resources (inside your res folder) and name it "anim", then create the animation resource files I included in my post  by right-clicking the anim directory in your IDE (eg. Android Studio) and selecting  New->Animation resource file. Copy -paste the code  I provided you with and experiment by calling it inside your onStart and onDestroy of the activities involved

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try and come back here. :-), thanks for helping out

Comment: you say: "You can't set transitions on your theme prior to Lollipop version but you can still use animations programmatically" , what's the difference between setting transitions in theme and doing it programmatically

Comment: @juztcode  (I should have mentioned that) You don't have access to the transitions API both in themes and programmatically. You can use animations as they were introduced  in older APIs